# How to determine language with twig and wmpl

Tags: wordpress, twig, wpml

I am trying to determine the language in a wordpress / twig website.
I tried the following in twig :

```
{{ wpml_current_lang }}
```

But that doesnt seem to work. Any idea's or suggestions ?

Comment: why do you need to determine the language?

Comment: Based on the info display the correct contry specific text/iamges, Like this for example:
{% if ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE == 'en' %}
    <p>Your button here</p>
{% endif %}

Answer (score 1):

This returns the language code as a string

```
{{ site.language }}
```

If you want to use logic you can do something like this

```
{% if site.language == 'en_GB' %}
do stuff
{% else % }
do other stuff
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this method to get a two letter language code: 
in index.php

```
$context['lang'] = strtolower( substr( get_locale(), 0, 2 ) );
```

then in the template.twig I could access lang like this:

```
 <!--language: {{lang}}-->
```

Of course, after I did this, I found out you could also use a build in constant, like described here: https://github.com/timber/timber/wiki/TimberSite

```
{{site.language}}
```

will give you the same as bloginfo('language') (this I did not test).